# how to pass along structure property via similar method to Bixby onclick

Tags: bixby

In a Bixby result-view on the Detail mode I want to provide the user with the option to select from one or more Actions and pass along a hidden parameter "identifier" that corresponds to a database field name to include in the http request made by the Action.

```
layout {
  match: AltBrainsData (this)

  mode (Details)

  content{

            section {
          content {
            image {
               //aspect-ratio (16:9)
               url {
       template ("#{value(this.icon_image)}")
        }
            }
          }
        }

        section {
          content {

              title-area {
                  slot1 {
                    text("[#{value(this.name)}]")
                    {style(Title_M)}
                  }
                }

          }
        }
        section {
          content {
            paragraph { value ("#{value(this.description)}") style (Detail_L) }
          }
        }
        section {
          content { 
           cell-card {
              slot2 {
              content {
                order (PrimarySecondary)
                primary ("Show me the latest news headlines")

              }
}
             on-click {
               intent {
                   goal: altbrains.persistencetest.GetNews
                   value: altbrains.persistencetest.AltBrainsData("#{value(this.identifier)}")
               }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ...
```

I get an error saying that the value must be a primitive.

How can I accomplish this?  Basically, I want the result "Detail" card to be populated with one or more possible Actions and each action should pass along this identifier to the corresponding function in code/.

A bit difficult to include all the necessary bits and pieces in Stack Overflow.  The money part of the GetNews function is:

```
function getNews(AltBrainsData) {

  const url = properties.get("config", "baseUrl") + "content"
  console.log("i got this far and the url is ", url);
  const query = {
    apikey: properties.get("secret", "apiKey"),
     q: "{\"" + "identifier" + "\":\"" + AltBrainsData.identifier + "\"}"

  }
```

Comment: I am a little confused. "value: altbrains.persistencetest.AltBrainsData("#{value(this.identifier)}")" are you trying to pass this.identifier as the input concept AltBrainData to action GetNews?

Comment: yes.  I want to pass this.identifier so that GetNews knows what records to retrieve from the database (i.e. those matching "identifier")

Comment: what is the concept type of this.identifier?

Comment: it is Core.Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to the following:

```
             on-click {
               intent {
                   goal: altbrains.persistencetest.GetNews
                   value: $expr(this)
               }
              }
```

You can read more about `$expr()` syntax in [expression language](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/customizing-plan.using-el#el-in-bixby-language)

Comment: no, i don't need to change any of the fields of ```this```

if I change only the line "value: ..." to read value: this

I get Line 49:202.0.0-altbrains.persistencetest.this is not a known concept or action
Line 49:20not a structure type: this

Comment: Answer updated, I think it's just the $expr syntax is not clearly explained in DOC

Comment: I have that so now I am trying to verify that (this) gets passed along to GetNews. I have this code in Get News to check:
```
var remoteDB = require('./lib/remoteDB.js')

var console = require('console')
console.log('i got here')
module.exports.function = function (AltBrainsData) {
  console.log(AltBrainsData)
  const identifier = AltBrainsData.identifier
  console.log('identifier', identifier)
  return remoteDB.getNews(identifier)
}
```
but I am getting TypeError cannot read property identifier from undefined.

Comment: Please let me know if you need further help. Or this issue is already resolved.

Comment: Still need help. Can I share my github repo? It's hard to describe all these interrelated pieces on Stack Overflow.

Comment: At the moment, I think it's just JS issue. `this` should be able to pass using $expr(this). You can submit a support ticket using Bixby IDE -> help -> contact support feature with the capsule synced.